# Rails4 Dalli ArgumentError key cannot be blank

Tags: memcached, ruby-on-rails-4, dalli, session-store

just run into an odd ArgumentError key cannot be blank error for a shiny Rails4 app with session store config to use memcache store

I've created an app to demo

https://github.com/khoan/rails4_dalli_session_store_error_app

ideas on how to fix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

We got this error too. Memcached is not down. It happen sometimes on production server and I managed to reproduce it on a pristine rails4 application using dalli_store or mem_cache_store as session_store. Sending a request with a forged blank session_id cookie will raise ArgumentError (key cannot be blank)

Comment: Managed to reproduce in a Rails 3 app with the same technique. Did you managed to workaround this?

Comment: I've submitted some patch on dalli that have been merged.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue as well. Dalli 2.7.2 fixes the issue([dalli@52f2208](https://github.com/mperham/dalli/commit/52f22086dadbb403533059dfe9b28d77b6ade9d4)), so I recommend upgrading.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly fixed the issue we were seeing and is well worth my +1.

Comment: I had the same experience. Thanks for figuring it was the gem.

Answer (score 2):

i got this error, too.
problem is memcached is down.(check application log)

check your memcached daemon!